# Use Cazeres/romaine lettuce leaves?

Tags: minhag, passover-seder-hagada, marror-bitter-herbs

I have seen some people use only the stalk and others use the whole leaf of the romaine lettuce for cazeres that they use by the Seder, both for the "plate" and for eating. What is the reason for the different customs?

Comment: It might be the result of bug checking or to avoid the problem of checking for bugs.

Comment: I have also the problem with horseradish. One uses the root. Why doesnt one use the leaves which are available and also taste bitter. According to the mishna one should rather use the leaves.

Comment: @newcomer According to the Mishna one _must_ use the leaves. The root is invalid.

Comment: I am well aware of that. @DoubleAA But they have some excuse to use the root.  I think since this is a root vegetable, only roots from the root are invalid

Comment: @DoubleAA Aren’t there some opinions that a root vegetable isn’t excluded by that, as it’s a modified root, and the only exclusion is for ordinary roots of non-root vegetables?

Comment: @Doniel there is an Acharon who says that a taproot is like a stalk not a root, but there are rishonim that write explicitly that the difference between stem and root is one grows above the ground and one grows below it.